# How to access MultiIndex column after groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, pandas-groupby, multi-index

With a single-indexed dataframe, the columns are available in the group by object:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,2,4,4], 'b': [5,6,7,8]})
df1.groupby('a')['b'].sum() -> 

a
2    11
4    15
```

But in a MultiIndex dataframe when not grouping by level, the columns are no longer accessible in the group by object

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df1], keys=['c', 'd'], axis=1)
df -> 

   c     d
   a  b  a  b
0  2  5  2  5
1  2  6  2  6
2  4  7  4  7
3  4  8  4  8

df.groupby([('c','a')])[('c','b')].sum() -> 
KeyError: "Columns not found: 'b', 'c'"
```

As a workaround, this works but it's not efficient since it doesn't use the cpythonized aggregator, not to mention it's awkward looking.

```
df.groupby([('c','a')]).apply(lambda df: df[('c', 'b')].sum())
```

Is there a way to access MultiIndex column in groupby object that I missed?

Comment: Adding a comma after your `('c','b')` tuple seems to work:  `df.groupby([('c','a')])[('c','b'),].sum()`.  I'm guessing that without the comma, pandas is just interpreting them as separate items.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding a comma after your `('c','b')` tuple seems to work:

```
df.groupby([('c','a')])[('c','b'),].sum()
```

I'm guessing that without the comma, pandas is just interpreting them as separate items.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answer, although it is somewhat unsatisfactory and maybe a more of a bug in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps explain the syntax:

```
df.groupby([('c','a')]).sum()

         c  d    
         b  a   b
(c, a)           
2       11  4  11
4       15  8  15

df.groupby([('c','a')])[('c','b'),('d','b')].sum()

         c   d
         b   b
(c, a)        
2       11  11
4       15  15
```